# Migrating from java 1.4 ,EJB 1 to Java 6 and EJB 3

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, ejb

I am working on very a old project ,the technologies used in that project are :

```
Java 1.4,
EJB 1.1
Weblogic 8.1
oracle 11g
```

I am thinking to migrate that project to `Java 1.6` ,`EJB 3.0` or `Spring 3 with Hibernate 4` ,`oracle weblogic 12`.

Can it be possible to migrate that project or not?

Could you please suggest me the possible steps I need to follow to acheive this.

Comment: If you want to go from Java 1.4 with EJB 1.1 to Spring 3 Hibernate 4, it's definitely going to be more realistic to just rewrite the project.

Comment: Can you please tell me than how can I migrate that project.I find difficulty working with java 1.4

Comment: Please be more precise on the problem that you encounter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's a huge step you are about to take.

In general, Java is fairly good in being backwards compatible.

The following is a list of changes that Oracle has listed for each release:

- [Java 5: New Features and Enhancements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/relnotes/features.html)
- [Java 6: Features and Enhancements](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/features-141434.html)

As for the EJB, There are big differences between EJB 1.1 and EJB 3.0 (I would recommend 3.1), 
which indeed need to be adjusted, I would start from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19501-01/819-3663/abmcj/index.html).

As for the database, If you will use the hibernate auto generate strategy, you wouldn't have problems with the script you had before (I imagine you had one !).

As for the application server, I imagine you would not have problems with it if it's freshly installed, of course as long as you are testing you project migration on it.

Hope this helps.